# OSX Finder - Folder hierarchy refresh working only for level 1

Tags: finder, folders

Let's say that we have a folder named Mother and inside another folder named child. If the file has been changed within the mother folder, finder modify by date sorting option works just fine and moves mother folder at the top of the list.

But if the files has been modified within child folder or even deeper in hierarchy modify by date doesn't work at all.

Does anyone have a solution to this?
macOS Big Sur Version 11.7.9